# Best way to integrate Git with Ant?

Tags: git, ant, integration

I am looking for the best way to integrate Git with Ant. Is there a widely used Ant task for Git? Does anyone have any experience using Git through Ant (e.g. dedicated task, exec call, etc)?

Comment: A more fine grained question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974106/how-to-lookup-the-latest-git-commit-hash-from-an-ant-build-script. The answers there might also be helpful here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doesn't look like there were a set of Ant tasks for Git.

[This blog](http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2008/11/13/ant-tasks-for-git/) talks about some rudimentary tasks for working with Git.

Comment: here is Git Ant Tasks via JGit http://aniszczyk.org/2011/05/12/git-ant-tasks-via-jgit/

Comment: This can only do `git clone`, `git init` and `git checkout`.

Answer (score 24):

Ant supports the [exec command](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) that you can use to pass any command (including Git) to the command line for execution. You can always fall back on that.

Answer (score 13):

Here is Git Ant Tasks via JGit: http://aniszczyk.org/2011/05/12/git-ant-tasks-via-jgit/ .

Answer (score 6):

[Look at  JGit-Ant](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Ant_Tasks). Unfortunately [jgit-ant](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Ant_Tasks) tasks project hasn't all main git actions, you can find additional info [here](https://github.com/SergeyBoguckiy/jgit-ant-tasks).

For java developers: you can easily write git-ant-commands yourself with using [jgit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide) as in [this examples](https://github.com/SergeyBoguckiy/jgit-ant-tasks).

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there has been some additional, unofficial work done on Ant tasks for git:

- http://github.com/newtriks/Ant-Funk (and blog post http://www.newtriks.com/?p=910)
- http://github.com/FrancisVarga/ant-git-macros

I don't have experience with these, but they appear more fleshed out than tlrobinson's.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the JGit library with some `<script language="javascript">` code (I used Rhino lubrary but you could equally use Groovy, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Time ago I have unsuccessfully looked for ready in use ways to integrate Git and Ant. I needed possibility to create a build with the name of the Git branch. Finally I came to the following solution:

The excerpt from the real `build.xml` file:

```
<target name="-check-git-branch-name"
    if="using.git"
    >
    <exec executable="bash" logError="true" failonerror="true"
        outputproperty="git-branch-name">
        <arg value="./bin/git-branch-name.sh" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The whole content of the file `./bin/git-branch-name.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is the part of integration GIT to ANT. Once launched it 
# should return the name of the current branch or the current commit (if 
# GIT is the detached HEAD mode). Further the printed name is appended to 
# the name of the resulting directory. To initialize this feature you need 
# to run ANT with the option "-Dusing.git=". 

exec 2>/dev/null

git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | grep -v HEAD || git rev-parse HEAD
```

Invocation is similar to:

```
ant TARGET options -Dusing.git=
```

When `${using.git}` is declared, Ant calls the task `-check-git-branch-name` to gather the name of a branch (or a commit's number if Git is in detached mode) and generates the build with the appended name of the Git branch (or commit's hnumber), for example `build/TARGET-${git-branch-name}`.