# How to get AndroidStudio's git path setting

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use the method described in this other SO question to generate the version info for an Android application:

[Automatically versioning Android project from git describe with Android Studio/Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097263/automatically-versioning-android-project-from-git-describe-with-android-studio-g/24121734#24121734)

The method depends on calling the `git` command from the gradle script. One requirement seems to be that `git` be in the path environment variable.

Is there a way to obtain this path from AndroidStudio's git settings?
(Version Control > Git: Path to Git Executable) I'd prefer if I didn't have to set up the environment variable and avoid hardcoding the directory where `git` is installed.

[image: screenshot of git configuration settings]

For reference, here's the method to obtain the version name from the linked question:

```
def getVersionName = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--dirty'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return stdout.toString().trim()
    }
    catch (ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```