# Process 'command 'git' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, git, gradle, revision-history

I want to implement an update revision number automatically in the manifest file.

Here is my code:

```
def getGitRevision(){
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD', '--count'
            args = ['info']
            standardOutput = os
        }
        def outputAsString = os.toString()
        def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev: (\d+)/

        ext.gitRev = "${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}".toInteger()
    }

    return String.valueOf(gitRev);
}
```

But it throws the following error:

> Error:(10, 0) Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Can you execute it with --info to get extended information about the failure?

Comment: What does this command print to std err stream?

Answer (score 0):

Open the 'settings.gradle' file, and then you may delete some code as follow:

```
exec {
    commandLine "git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive"
}
```

After finished this, you can't use the git function, but it worked for me to compile successfully.