# How to escape double quotes while executing on command line through gradle?

Tags: git, gradle

I am trying to include my application's version through git using gradle build system. I want to run the following command to get the version info from git:

```
git describe --tags --match "v[0-9]*"
```

After reading the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097263/automatically-versioning-android-project-from-git-describe-with-android-studio-g), I am using the following gradle syntax:

```
commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--long', '--match "v[0-9]*"'
```

but it gives error in execution.

> error: unknown option `match v[0-9]*'

I have tried escaping the double quote with backslash, but that does not work either. Can someone please point me towards a correct way of executing above command through gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it should be:

```
commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--long', '--match', 'v[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `'--match "v[0-9]*"'` the version number should be part of the command. So you can put them in an own section something like this:

`commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--long', '--match', 'v[0-9]*'`

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

When you look here at the description

> **commandLine**   The full command line, including the executable plus its
>   arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I am accepting Opal's answer though because he answered before you. :)