# How to get total number of count for git tags

Tags: git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, versioning

I want to get the total number of tag count in a repository

The [grgit](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit) repository already solves the problem.

```
git = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open()
git.tag.list().size()
```

But its in groovy and I want a gradle version of it.

```
git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --count)
```

Above code gives total number of commits

I have the following snippet so far which gets the total number of commits.

```
versionCode = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', '--first-parent', '--count', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(stdout.toString().trim())
    }
    catch (ignored) {
        return -1
    }
}
```

I have referenced [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17097263/1336154) but without proper answer

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind using commands besides git... `git tag | wc -l`

Comment: yes this works well on command-line, but I am trying to put in inside gradle script. Let me try it, if you have the solution do edit your answer

Comment: `x=0; git for-each-ref refs/tags | while read ref; do x=$((x+1)); echo $x; done | tail -n1`

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out with the below solution. @EncryptedWatermelon answer helped me get to this Solution. However I am more open to a better solution then this.

```
getVersionCode = {
    def proc = 'git tag'.execute() | 'wc -l'.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    return proc.text
}
```

@EncryptedWatermelon Thanks for the hint.

Comment: just an fyi, to show appreciation for an answer/comment, be sure to "up vote". As in, EncryptedWatermelon's comment should be upvoted.