# How to set android app version by number of build in Jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Application is automatically building by jenkins after successful push, but version is always 1.0. Instead of "0" I want to insert number of corresponding build in jenkins: 1.119, 1.120, 1.121...

That is my build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
gradle clean 
gradle build
#. run_android_ui_tests.sh
```

My gradle.properities contains only comments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Problem solved by inserting these two strings into build.gradle's defaultConfig:

```
def env = System.getenv()
versionName "1." + env['BUILD_NUMBER']
```

instead of

```
versionName "1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some preprocessing of your Manifest or build.gradle.

Fro example

1. 1st build step is to run some script to paste version that you need.
2. 2nd build step is to build you app.

I recommend you to get a system value that you can determine in each build you have, so you can change version of the app yourself in build configuration.

Comment: Okay, what is the command that I have to insert? As I understand I should paste something like "gradle.setAppVersion("1." + String.valueOf(getLasJenkinsBuildNumber() + 1))" in java. But how this string really looks like in bash?

Comment: You can find examples of what you need here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895123/auto-version-numbering-your-android-app-using-git-and-eclipse for example. Or here http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/02/14/build-your-android-apk-with-the-manifest-version-number

Answer (score 0):

Best approach will be to use gradle release plugin for this. Using this you can do automatic version inclement version in your manifest file. You can have a [look here](https://github.com/ari/gradle-release-plugin)

You can use it for tagging your source tree as well for different versions.

Answer (score 0):

the configuration at the build.gradle should be

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    versionName System.getenv("APP_VERSION") as String ?: "3.0.0 (Default)"

    ...
}
```

[Jenkins Configuration for parse the build parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXngE.png)