# How to call git show --first-parent in jgit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need to get the commits from master that are not of type merge and do not come from other branches (they were directly put on master). 
  The git command is

> git log --no-merges --first-parent

How can I do this using JGit? 
  I managed to get the commits that are not of type merge using

```
RevFilter.NO_MERGES
```

But how can I get the commits that were commited direct into master branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `RevWalk` with a custom filter that ignores all commits except the first parent.

```java
class FirstParentFilter extends RevFilter {
  private Set<RevCommit> ignoreCommits = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public boolean include( RevWalk revWalk, RevCommit commit ) throws IOException {
    if( commit.getParentCount() > 1 ) {
      ignoreCommits.add( commit.getParent( 1 ) );
    }
    boolean include = true;
    if( ignoreCommits.contains( commit ) ) {
      include = false;
      ignoreCommits.remove( commit );
    }
    return include;    
  }

  @Override
  public RevFilter clone() {
    return new FirstParentFilter();
  }
}
```

The simplistic filter assumes that there are two parents at most but could easily be extended to handle more than two parents.

Combined with the `NO_MERGES` filter and topological sorting (all children before parents) it should do what you were looking for

```java
revWalk.sort( RevSort.TOPO );
revWalk.setRevFilter( AndRevFilter.create( new FirstParentFilter(), RevFilter.NO_MERGES ) );
```

The following is the simple merge scenario I used to test the filter:

```java
git.commit().setMessage( "base" ).call();
String master = git.getRepository().getFullBranch();
Ref side = git.branchCreate().setName( "side" ).call();
git.commit().setMessage( "master" ).call();
git.checkout().setName( side.getName() ).call();
git.commit().setMessage( "side" ).call();
git.merge().include( git.getRepository().getRef( master ) ).setFastForward( NO_FF ).setMessage( "merge" ).call();

try( RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( git.getRepository() ) ) {
  revWalk.setRevFilter( AndRevFilter.create( new FirstParentFilter(), RevFilter.NO_MERGES ) );
  revWalk.sort( RevSort.TOPO );
  Ref headRef = git.getRepository().getRef( Constants.HEAD );
  RevCommit headCommit = revWalk.parseCommit( headRef.getObjectId() );
  revWalk.markStart( headCommit );
  for( RevCommit revCommit : revWalk ) {
    System.out.println( revCommit.getShortMessage() );
  }
}
```

Output

```
side
base
```

Comment: Unfortunately , it does not work as expected. I get commits that comes from other merges/pull requests .

Comment: Please provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem - either append it to this quesstion or post a new one.

Comment: I want to say . for example: given two branches: master and testing .I make some commits on testing branch ,than I create a pull request from master to get all the modifications from testing. After this pull request , on master branch there are commits that came from testing branch. I want to get the commits from master that do not come from other branches.

Comment: A small, standalone snippet/test case that initializes a repository, creates the (merge-) commits that you desribe, lists them with a RevWalk, and asserts/shows what is expected and what not would be good.

Comment: actually the `--first-parent` removes all the parent and the commits that are parents to it until the common parent of the current commit is reached. This code only ignores the parent commits - save first -, which is not desired. You can test this on a more complex repo and see the difference.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann the trick is not to use the `RevWalk` for visiting the commits, rather, to use the `getParent()` on the commit and manually do the work.

Comment: @Avinash R You are right, manually traversing the history solves the problem. You'd of course have to handle multiple start refs and sorting also manually - if that's required.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, Maybe that's something the `RevWalk` API is missing, traversing a tree as a tree instead of a set of commits

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann there is even developments for this to be integrated in the `RevWalk`. More in [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg03017.html) jgit mailing thread

Answer (score 6):

For getting the first parent, you could just call the [`RevCommit.getParent()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.1.1.201511131810-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html#getParent(int)) and work your way from there.

The rationale behind not using a [`RevWalk`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.1.1.201511131810-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html) for visiting the tree is that `RevWalk` walks through revs without following the hierarchy -- i.e., if you didn't read the commit, it's parent will be read --, which is not what `--first-parent` does, and what we want here.

So [Rüdiger Herrmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054511/1523910) will fail to remove the commits made on (n+1,...)<sup>th</sup> branches. It would only remove the first commit made on those branches.

#### Code

```
Repository repo = git.getRepository();
try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo)) {
    RevCommit head = walk.parseCommit(repo.getRef(MASTER).getObjectId());
    int count = 0;
    while (head != null) {
        count++;
        RevCommit[] parents = head.getParents();
        if (parents != null && parents.length > 0) {
            head = walk.parseCommit(parents[0]);
        } else {
            head = null;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

*This is converted from groovy [source](https://gist.github.com/Avinash-Bhat/12fc59b3d96cb427e5e9)*

#### Notes

1. The call to `walk.parseCommit(parents[0])` is required as the commits returned by `.getParents()` will not be parsed completely, and will give `null` on calling `.getParents()` on themselves.
2. This was written for finding version code from git repo for Android build script (gradle) based on my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584169/1523910). (see [source](https://gist.github.com/Avinash-Bhat/12fc59b3d96cb427e5e9))